# How do I mock the imports my tested class makes with jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to setup tests for my database crawler program and I can't manage to replace what the class method I'm testing imports.

So as not to write down too much code I'll just lay out the general form of the problem. In my test function I have:

```
describe("test",()=>{
  let result1;

  beforeAll(async ()=>{
    await createConnection();
  })

  afterAll(async ()=>{
    getConnection().close();
  })

  test("setup test",async () => {
    result1 = await WeatherController.startForecastAPI();
    expect(result1.status).toBe(Status.SUCCESS);
  })
})
```

The WeatherController.ts file (... where code was taken out):

```
...
import AccessTokenService from '../services/AccessTokenService';

export default class WeatherController{
    ...
    static async startForecastAPI(){
           ...
           const accessToken = AccessTokenService.getAccessToken();//get and validate token 
           ...        
    }
}
```

Inside the WeatherController class, startForecastAPI is defined as a static async method. The class imports multiple other classes, among them the AccessTokenService class which is used to get valid access tokens. AccessTokenService.getAccessToken() should return an object with several properties that it gets through a http request.

I want to mock the results of calling AccessTokenService but I'm not calling it directly in my test function, I'm calling WeatherController and WeatherController is calling AccessTokenService. How can I replace what WeatherController calls when I test it but without touching the WeatherController code? I've tried going through the jest docs but I'm fairly new to all of this and they're confusing. I'm not entirely clear how scoping works here either (I tried defining a function in the test code and calling it in the tested function but it's out of scope).

The await WeatherController.startForecastAPI() call in the test function returns undefined but the code works fine when I hard-code accessToken to be a valid object, I just can't find a way to inject that object into the code through the test function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming AccessTokenService.getAccessToken returns a promise or is an async function, then you can use jest.spyOn(...).mockResolvedValue() to prevent calling the server

```
describe("test",()=>{
  let result1;

  beforeAll(async ()=>{
    await createConnection();
  })

  afterAll(async ()=>{
    getConnection().close();
  })

  test("setup test",async () => {
    const expectedResultFromGetToken = {property: 'property 1'};
    const getTokenSpy = jest.spyOn(AccessTokenService, 'getAccessToken')
                            .mockResolvedValue(expectedResultFromGetToken)
    result1 = await WeatherController.startForecastAPI();
    expect(result1.status).toBe(Status.SUCCESS);
    expect(getTokenSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

if the AccessTokenService.getAccessToken is not an async function then you have to use jest.spyOn(...).mockReturnValue()

Comment: I added more info into my post.

Comment: What you need to do is, in your test case you can spy on the AccessTokenService.getAccessToken by doing jest.spyOn(AccessTokenService, 'getAccessToken').mockResolvedValue({propert1: 'I'm a mocked object'})

Comment: Editing my answer now

Answer (score 0):

If inside your class you have

```
const AccessToken = require('access-token');
```

you can mock it with

```
jest.mock('access-token', () => {
   function getToken() {
     return 'fakeToken'
   }
);

const WeatherController = require('weather-controller');

describe("test",()=>{
  let result1;

  beforeAll(async ()=>{
    await createConnection();
  })

  afterAll(async ()=>{
    getConnection().close();
  })

  test("setup test",async () => {
    result1 = await WeatherController.startForecastAPI();
    expect(result1.status).toBe(Status.SUCCESS);
  })
})
```